# xmpp pubsub: presence based delivery

Tags: xmpp, openfire

The "presence_based_delivery" simply doesn't work on openfire or am I missing something? Must "subscription-options" be filled out by the subscriber?

This is what I did:

1. Node configuration

   ```
   "pubsub#presence_based_delivery" = 1 
   "pubsub#deliver_payloads" = 1
   "pubsub#persist_items" = 1
   "pubsub#max_items" = -1 (for infinite number of items)
   ```
2. User1 subscribes to NodeA and goes offline.
3. User2 who is subscribed to the NodeA publishes an item to it.
4. User1 goes online but does not receive any notification of the published item.

Answer (score 0):

According to the extension's documentation, presence_based delivery won't send an event to the user if he was offline:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#impl-offline